# Associated subgroup of Weyl group

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group, weights

Let $\Phi$ be a root system.
For a weight $\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$,
start by defining

$
\Phi_{[\lambda]}:=\{\alpha\in \Phi \ | \ \langle \lambda,\alpha^{\lor}\rangle\in\mathbb{Z} \}
$
and
$
W_{[\lambda]}:=\{w\in W \ | \ w\lambda-\lambda\in \Lambda_r\},
$ where $\Lambda_r$ is the root lattice. (i.e., $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $\Phi$)

Fix a weight $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*$, if $\lambda-\mu$ is an integral weight, then 
$
\Phi_{[\lambda]}=\Phi_{[\mu]} \ \text{and } W_{[\lambda]}=W_{[\mu]}.
$.

In section 3.4 of ***Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}$.***

We have the following fact:
$W_{[\lambda]}$ is the Weyl group of the root system $\Phi_{[\lambda]}$.

I would like to **make sure** whether $W_{[\lambda]}$ is a ***parabolic subgroup*** of $W$.

In my opinion, I think the answer is **yes**. Can anyone prove or disprove that?

Comment: Doesn't the exercise in Section 3.4 of the book give you a counterexample? For $\Phi$ of type $B_2$ with short simple root $\alpha$, for $\lambda = \alpha / 2$ you have $\Phi_{[\lambda]}$ of type $A_1 \times A_1$.

Comment: Most of it can be guessed at, but you might like to define the welter of notation here.  (I guess that $\Lambda_r$ is the root lattice.)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Sorry for missing that part.